# Is there a way to view the complete "Additional Information" log of Ghidra's "Import Results Summary"?

Tags: dll, ghidra, import-reconstruction

I'm currently trying to look into Q.U.B.E. 2's internal mechanics, so I decided to look at it using Ghidra. Q.U.B.E. 2 is built upon UnrealEngine, so it it's pretty big (~50 Mb's). However, when importing the file, Ghidra complains about a lot of missing DLLs. So I started downloading all of them manually and putting them into a directory which I specified in the import settings -> External Libraries, however, the missing files only get written in the "Additional Info" field of the import results.

The problem here is, that the "Additional Info" ends with the following message:

```
There were too many messages to display.
659 messages have been truncated.
```

meaning I can't take a look at all of the missing dll's.

I can't have a good look into the code without the dependencies, as Ghidra displays `No symbol` warning's everywhere. My guess is that a big thing of Unreal Engine is still missing, as most of the missing symbols start with `U` (`UObjectBase`, `UWorld`, ...)

Can I somehow look at the complete import log to add the missing libraries? Or is there a faster way to supply every dependency?